# Chroot is not working on suse 9 rescue system?

Tags: suse, rescue

I need to recover a server with suse 9, but I'm facing a very common error of `chroot` not working. It is complaining that `/bin/bash` does not exist, but it exists.

These are  the commands I've used:

```
mount /dev/dvg/lv00 /mnt
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev

cd /

chroot /mnt
```

But it fails with no such file or directory.

`ldd` on `/mnt/bin/bash` shows that every needed library is available.

Strace does not help at all.

`/mnt/bin/bash -i` works with no error.

Any help on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the libraries are available in `/mnt`. Typically, from each libraries listed by `ldd /mnt/bin/bash` there is an homologous in `/mnt`?

If you try `/mnt/bin/bash` from your shell (`ldd` or `/mnt/bin/bash -i`), libraries will still be got from `/lib` or `/lib64`.

When you use `chroot /mnt`, everything will be get from `/mnt/*`.

Typically (from a Debian), I have four libraries to check (the first line doesn't count):

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc8783000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f1a1000b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1a10005000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1a0fe30000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1a1017f000)
```

You should check these four (adjust depending of you `ldd` output) are available in `/mnt`. Be carefull, most are symlinks and the pointed files must also be available in `/mnt` too.

I have to admit that `strace` doesn't help since the `execve` syscall returns an error when there is a missing library.

Comment: All libraries are available in /mnt/lib.

Comment: I've tried everything. But to no avail. Any ideas?